# SQL Error: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'

Tags: sql, sql-server, jpa, interface

I have the below sql which works in sql studio

```
Declare @where nvarchar(MAX) = 'ORG_TYPE_CODE LIKE ''%INC%''' 

Declare @sql nvarchar(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM C_B_ORG_DTL WHERE '+@where+' AND HUB_STATE_IND=1' 

Exec sp_executeSQL @sql
```

I am trying to implement this in JPA

```
@Query(value = "Declare @where nvarchar(MAX) = ?1 " +
        "Declare @sql nvarchar(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM C_B_ORG_DTL WHERE '+@where+' AND HUB_STATE_IND=1' " +
        "Exec sp_executeSQL @sql", nativeQuery = true)
List<CBPty> getAllCompanies(String orgType);
```

I am getting the error

```
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'
```

How do I make it work? Thanks in advance

Comment: `PRINT` the value of `@SQL`, it's the easiest way to debug dynamic statements. However, injecting an entire `WHERE` clause is a dangerous window to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working. I had syntax issue in the @where parameter passed in.

```
@Query(value = " DECLARE @where nvarchar(MAX)" +
            " SET @where = (?1) " +
            " EXEC('SELECT * FROM C_B_ORG_DTL WHERE '+@where+' AND HUB_STATE_IND=1' )", nativeQuery = true)
List<CBPty> getAllCompanies(String orgType);
```

We need to use EXEC if we are running dynamically generated pieces in the sql. Hopefully this would be useful if somebody facing the similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```
@Query(value = "Declare @where nvarchar(MAX) =** ?1** " +
        "Declare @sql nvarchar(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM C_B_ORG_DTL WHERE '+@where+' AND HUB_STATE_IND=1' " +
        "Exec sp_executeSQL @sql", nativeQuery = true)
List<CBPty> getAllCompanies(String orgType);
```

if you write the query after replacing it turn into:

```
SELECT * FROM C_B_ORG_DTL WHERE 1 AND HUB_STATE_IND=1
```

If you look at in Where section in combining  `@where` variable that you must use the boolean expression in there like

```
 SELECT * FROM C_B_ORG_DTL WHERE ORG_TYPE_CODE LIKE '%INC%' AND HUB_STATE_IND=1;
```